# How to convert List of Lists in Scala json4s

Tags: scala, json4s

I have trouble to convert scala struct to json. I use library json4s.

```
val asanaList = Seq(("007", 536), ("008", 888))
println(compact(render(asanaList)))
```

The result is:

```
[{"007":536},{"008":888}]
```

I need something like:

```
[["007",536],["008",888]]
```

This example don't work either:

```
val asanaList = Seq(Seq("007", 536), Seq("008", 888))
```

Comment: Have you tried  `Seq(Seq("007", "536"), Seq("008", "888"))`  OR `Seq(Seq(007, 536), Seq(008, 888))`? Any special reasons you want two different types in your sequence ?

Comment: My original json was `[{"id":"007", "duration":536}, ...]`. I just wanted to shorten it. `Seq(Seq("007", "536"), Seq("008", "888"))` work like a charm. I think I must use it.